# Install .cer certificate in "Trusted Devices" folder via PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I need to install .cer certificate into "Trusted Devices" folder because I have PowerShell script which automatically installs software and only thing that is blocks the hole script is windows which asks about trustworthy of the dongle driver.

I use this cmdlet inside Vagrant

```
 vagrant.exe powershell -c "Import-Certificate -Filepath C:\vagrant\Microcosm.cer -CertStoreLocation Cert:\Local Computer\TrustedDevices"
```

Here is error message output

```
vagrant.exe : The following WinRM command responded with a non-zero exit status.
At line:1 char:2
+  vagrant.exe powershell -c "Import-Certificate -Filepath C:\vagrant\Microcosm.ce ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (The following W...ro exit status.:String) [], RemoteException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError

Vagrant assumes that this means the command failed!
Import-Certificate -Filepath C:\vagrant\Microcosm.cer -CertStoreLocation Cert:\Local Computer\TrustedDevices
Stdout from the command:
Stderr from the command:
#< CLIXML
<Objs Version="1.1.0.1" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/powershell/2004/04"><S S="Error">Import-Certificate : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'Computer\Trust
edDevices'._x000D__x000A_</S><S S="Error">At line:1 char:40_x000D__x000A_</S><S S="Error">+ ... lyContinue';Import-Certificate -Filepath C:\vagrant\Microcosm.cer -Ce ..._x000D__x000A_</S><S 
S="Error">+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~_x000D__x000A_</S><S S="Error">    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Import-Certificate], P
arameterBindingException_x000D__x000A_</S><S S="Error">    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound,Microsoft.CertificateServices.Commands.ImportCertificateComm _x000D__x000A_</
S><S S="Error">   and_x000D__x000A_</S><S S="Error"> _x000D__x000A_</S></Objs>
```

Answer (score 0):

Cert:\Local Computer\TrustedDevices has a space in it. Try this with escaped quotes around your path:

```
vagrant.exe powershell -c "Import-Certificate -Filepath C:\vagrant\Microcosm.cer -CertStoreLocation `"Cert:\Local Computer\TrustedDevices`""
```

Comment: Thanks, BenH. When I executed your command I got an issue

vagrant.exe : The machine with the name 'Computer\TrustedDevices' was not found configured for
At line:1 char:1
+ vagrant.exe powershell -c "Import-Certificate -Filepath C:\vagrant\Microcosm.cer ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (The machine wit... configured for:String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError